# Deadline exceed error in task queue with Basic module (Google app engine)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, task, push-queue

I'm using python Google App engine SDK and Django framework.
In my case, the task queue is throwing deadline exceed error

> DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded.

though using task queue in basic scaling and as per [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push?hl=en#task_deadlines) task in basic or manual scaling can run up to 24 hours.

Task is updating all MySQL DB values so is time-consuming.

Initiating a task by sending post request in

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_url(request):
 params= dict(.......)#some dict
 taskqueue.add(url='/tasks/gcm/gcm_all_user/',
                          params=params,
                          method="POST")
 return Response('Initiated task')
```

this task is dispatched to basic scaling module by dispatch.yaml

```
dispatch:
- url: "*/tasks/*"
  module: tasks
```

the task module have a handler for url

```
application: some-application
module: tasks
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
basic_scaling:

libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"

handlers:
- url: /tasks.*
  script: app.wsgi.application
```

Kindly could anyone tell how to make task run for longer without deadline exceed error.

Comment: What is the contents of your queue.yaml  Do you have one ?

Comment: No I dont didn't created a queue.yaml @TimHoffman

Comment: Its working now after adding 
`basic_scaling:   max_instances: 1` and `handlers:
- url: /_ah/start
  script: oodles.wsgi.application`

Answer (score 0):

The task can run for as long as you need it, but HTTP requests have their own deadlines. You may need to refactor the code that runs within your task - possibly, breaking one large request into a series of smaller requests.